# Add macro in excel file

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I'm trying to add a macro while generating the excel using c#.net code. While generating excel I got this error

> Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted

I understand I have to make the macro trusted in an excel option.
How can I active this in c#.code?

This is the code I have used.

```
StringBuilder sb;
VBIDE.VBComponent xlModule; 
sb = new StringBuilder();

xlApp.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityByUI;
 sb.AppendLine("Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)");
sb.AppendLine("Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents");
xlModule = wrkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule); 
xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Try to mark `Trust Access to the VBA Project object model` as checked in Trust Center => Macro Settings from Excel options menu.

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto - I wanted to achive thorw C#.code , user can't set every time in excel options rite.

Comment: It can, theoretically, be changed using the VBIDE which you seem able to access from your c# code. I've also seen suggestions that the change doesn't take effect until the **user** closes Excel and re-opens it. Programmatic close doesn't save the change.

Googling also found VBScript to change the Registry setting.

Answer (score 0):

It can be changed trough the [registry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cristib/2012/02/29/vba-how-to-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros/):

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" 
                                   + xlApp.Version + "\Excel\Security", "AccessVBOM", 1);
```